# When i use 'group' in cakephp , pagination not work

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have model `IndividualSystemSerialNumber` in `cakephp1.3`  and when i try to `group by` `mac_address` pagination not working.

But when i remove `group` from paginate , it's working fine.

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'order' => $order_by,
    'group' => 'IndividualSystemSerialNumber.mac_address',
    'page' => intval($page),
    'limit' => $this->params['url']['iDisplayLength']
);

$systems = $this->paginate('IndividualSystemSerialNumber');
```

Comment: I am not sure about 1x versions.. But, have you tried considering recursive option?

Comment: ya i have tried but still not not working. if i remove group condition its working fine.

Comment: Define paginator outside... like so: `var $paginator = array('limit' => 20);`

Comment: @KarmicDice i think `limit` in `$this->paginate` doing that...

Comment: @KarmicDice i have already set `limit` inside `$this->paginate`

Comment: @DevangRathod i think you misunderstood what he is tring to say

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problem as you have now i don't know but `paginate` has some problem when you use `group` option.

So here is alternative solution that will work just awesome.

**Example**

```
$systems = $this->IndividualSystemSerialNumber->find('all',array
(
    'order'  => $order_by,
    'group' => 'IndividualSystemSerialNumber.mac_address',
    'page'  => intval($page),
    'limit'  => $this->params['url']['iDisplayLength'],
    'fields' => array
    (
        'IndividualSystemSerialNumber.mac_address',
        //other related fields.
    )
));
```

You have `$page` that is number of page you are requesting and `Model::find()` has option called `page` that accept currently requested page number and you also have `limit` set so above code will work as `$this->paginate();`

Cheers Enjoy Coding.